# PimCore with VueJS and VueJS-Router

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, pimcore

How do i make an extension for Pimcore with VueJs and the VueJS-Router? 
 
So far no problems with vuejs in the frontend … but i cant get the VueJs-Router running.

Does any anyone has an experience with VueJs Routing inside of a pimcore extension?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use HTML5 History Mode?

Answer (score 1):

if pimcore has main.js

put the router there

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

then use

Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define primcore layout and route properly to make vue-router work.

1. Define a layout working with vuejs
2. Define a route /(.*) to a view extended that layout

If you don't define wildcard route to vue layout, then primcore will handle url instead of vue-router. Hopes it helps.

Primcore custom routes documentation:
https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/MVC/Routing_and_URLs/Custom_Routes.html

Answer (score 0):

install vue-router with

npm install vue-router

then use

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

you can see more details about vue-router in officail website: https://router.vuejs.org/installation.html